# How to Write HTML Content in PDF file using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to write HTML content in PDF using PDFBox using JAVA. How can I write it ? Is there any method by which I can add HTML Content ? There are different add methods but not able to add HTML content.

Comment: Not at all. PDFBox doesn't have a HTML parser.

Comment: It means, we have to use other api to write HTML in PDF. Right ?

Comment: Another tool, not another API.

Comment: @LalitBhudiya did you get a solution to these issues, east-west I seem to always land on your question. Your response is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no html rendering support yet in pdfbox as of 2.0.6. But heard about few commitments on this feature in their future releases.

Comment: I didn't hear that. And I should know, I am a PDFBox committer.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I also can't seem to find documentation or a solution to writing html to pdf using pdfbox

Comment: It is not supported. There are tools on top of pdfbox like opdnhtmltopdf.

Comment: Oops openhtmltopdf.

Answer (score -3):

you can do same thing using IText also, use this code.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String ... args ) {
    try {
      Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("E:\\yogesh\\test.pdf"));
      document.open();
      document.addAuthor("author");
      document.addSubject("subject");
      document.addCreationDate();
      document.addTitle("title");

      HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
      String str = "<html><head></head><body>"+
        "<table border='1'><tr><td>Demo<td>" +
        "<td bgcolor='red'>DEMO<td></tr>DEMO</table>" +
        "</body></html>";
      htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
      document.close();
      System.out.println("Done");
      }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know, I can do using iText but I want to use Apache PDFBox.

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated.